# Is using the AES crypto with a salt secure enough

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I was looking at some GitHub code and saw a function like this:

```
function computeHash(password, salt, fn) {
    // Bytesize
    var len = 128;
    var iterations = 4096;

    if (3 == arguments.length) {
        crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, len, fn);
    } else {
        fn = salt;
        crypto.randomBytes(len, function(err, salt) {
            if (err) return fn(err);
            salt = salt.toString('base64');
            crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, len, function(err, derivedKey) {
                if (err) return fn(err);
                fn(null, salt, derivedKey.toString('base64'));
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The above is called like so in a JS lamba function:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
v    ar email = event.email;
    var clearPassword = event.password;

    computeHash(clearPassword, function(err, salt, hash) { ...
```

Is this a secure enough approach
How do I get to use SSL to get the data from the iphone to lambda (is there an easy way to turn it on in AWS)?

Comment: Secure enough for what? What are you protecting? Who are your attackers? What resources do they have; how committed are they to getting this data; how much time do they have over which this information is sensitive? 4096 is a very low number of iterations, but it is reasonably common in the JavaScript world (JS is too slow for more typical iteration counts of 10-100k). What is done with this hash? How is the AES performed (there's no AES here)? How is the HMAC (for CBC) performed? But absent any details, sure, PBKDF2 is generally a good way derive keys from passwords.

Comment: it's just a auth system I was building. so email and passwords then just regular (text, images, etc.) user data after auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the computeHash() function, it is using [salted hashes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure-for-password-storage) which is a standard and reasonably secure means of storing passwords. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47183/is-it-safe-to-use-pbkdf2-for-hashing. As @RobNapier says, your mileage may vary.

To get the password from your device to the Lambda function, use the [AWS API Gateway and Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html):

> AWS Lambda provides an easy way to build back ends without managing
>   servers. API Gateway and Lambda together can be powerful to create and
>   deploy serverless Web applications. In this walkthrough, you learn how
>   to create Lambda functions and build an API Gateway API to enable a
>   Web client to call the Lambda functions synchronously.

In Lambda you can easily create a API endpoint URL to expose your function.  The API endpoints use the HTTPS protocol by default, so SSL is already provided.

Comment: so by following that tutorial above i should be able to call secure/ssl encrypted lambda functions from my ios device?

Comment: Sweet. I am going through the process now. Do I need to create a new IAM user: http://screencast.com/t/sdW6t7ei06b3

Comment: I am curious about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516318/creating-and-amazon-api-gateway-for-aws-lambda-functions